# Как использовать <template> в Internet explorer 11?

Tags: javascript, html5, internet-explorer

Появилась необходимость поддерживать IE. И я хочу удобный способ использовать шаблоны html кода.
Проблема в том, что он не совсем верно обрабатывает `<template>`
Подскажите как я могу использовать что то похожее на `<template>` но в IE?

### Решение?

Поискав в интернете варианты, **которые не подразумевают подключение дополнительных зависимостей**, я нашел такое решение:

```js
var htmlDiv_MainContainer = document.querySelector('#id_MainContainer');

var htmlTemplate_DivElement = document.querySelector('#id_Template');

var htmlDiv_TemplateElement = htmlTemplate_DivElement.cloneNode(true);

htmlDiv_TemplateElement.querySelector('#id_Div').textContent = 'Текст для вставки';
htmlDiv_TemplateElement.removeAttribute('hidden');
htmlDiv_MainContainer.appendChild(htmlDiv_TemplateElement);
```

```html
<div id="id_MainContainer"></div>
<div id="id_Template" hidden>
  <div id="id_Div"></div>
</div>
```

Но, так как я новичек в web development, я не уверен что это хорошее решение...
Если Вы считаете, что задачу по шаблонизации можно решить иначе, буду рад вашим комментариям и ответам.

Comment: Десять раз прочитал, так  и не понял ничего...

Comment: Сори, забыл экранировать теги в тексте

Comment: А  что именно ты хочешь сделать? для каких целей?

Comment: Ну использовать повторно куски html кода

Comment: можно просто их клонировать...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В данном случае тебе поможет

```
document.createDocumentFragment();
```

Подробности [Тут](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Document/createDocumentFragment)
И [Тут](https://learn.javascript.ru/multi-insert)
Это как раз для старых браузеров